# Wrong date in moment.js when used with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs

**With express**

```
const express = require('express');
const moment = require('moment');

const app = express();

const generateSearchRange = (year) => (month) => {
    return {
        start: 0,
        stop: moment([year]).endOf('year')
    }
};

app.get('/foo/:year', (req, res) => {
   const year = req.params.year; // 2017
    res.send(generateSearchRange(year)(12)); // { "start": 0, "stop": "2016-12-31T22:59:59.999Z" }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**Without express**

```
const moment = require('moment');

const generateSearchRange = (year) => (month) => {
    return {
        start: 0,
        stop: moment([year]).endOf('year')
    }
};

console.log(generateSearchRange(2017)(12)); // { start: 0, stop: moment("2017-12-31T23:59:59.999") }
```

I don't undestand what's happening that the same function gives me two different outputs.

Comment: I'm guessing that since response needs string in this case, it implicity calls the toString method on moment object, and hence you get it's string representation in the response. I would suggest you log the data in express just before sending, it should confirm to what you see on the standalone script

Comment: @Malice Take a look at my answer below. I found that this code works properly in virtual machine so that's something with my OS. Now I need to locate this problem :D

Comment: Could you just try my suggestion once

Answer (score 0):

It works properly with me. I've just copied your code

Comment: maybe you should make sure that the parameter is 2017 in your browser and there's no middleware messes with the param

Comment: You're right. I ran this on virtual machine and everything works properly. So that's something with my system. Any ideas where the source of this problem might be?

Comment: @gregooroo I Just ran the code on windows with git bash and got the same mismatch. Are you using a similar setup ?

Answer (score 0):

The string representation of moment is used by express to construct response. It calls toString method to do this. You can confirm this by logging the date before adding to response.

```
let date = generateSearchRange(year)(12);
console.log(date)
res.send(date);
```

Comment: Ok. I did that. Now in console I see "{ start: 0, stop: moment("2017-12-31T23:59:59.999") }" but in postman { "start": 0, "stop": "2017-12-31T22:59:59.999Z" } the output is still wrong when I'm running this code on my OS.

Comment: Yes, this means your middle ware is converting moment object to a date string, this is the standard behaviour. Response needs strings to be rendered, but you passed an object to construct response, so express converts to a string.

Comment: Ok but when I run the same code on my virtual machine (my own vagrant box - with debian 8) everything works well.

Comment: Works well as in, are you getting `moment()` in api response on postman?

Comment: I bet you are using different node/moment version on the VM

Comment: Yea... On my host OS I have node v9.3.0 and on virtual machine v.8.9.0

Comment: and moment version ?

Comment: 2.20.1. I also tried on 2.19.1 but it still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: As I said,  your code doesnt have any problem, you are seeing the difference between the string conversion in `console.log` and express middleware , using  `toString()`. The values do remain the same

Comment: And the change in output between the machines is because of the difference in node versions

Comment: Now I changed moment([year]).endOf('year') to  moment([year]).utc(1).endOf('year') and seems like everything works well on both my host and virtual box..